# I need help aligning image links in the center of my page

Tags: html, css

I would like to align the image links to the center of the page. This is what I have tried so far:

**HTML:**

```
<section id="Contact">
  <h1 class="other-section">Contact</h1>
  <div class="contact-links">
    <a id="profile-link" href="https://facebook.com/" target="_blank">
     <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/21/21155.svg" />
    </a>
    <a id="profile-link" href="https://github.com/jadenadams329" target="_blank">
       <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25231.svg" />
     </a>
    <a id="profile-link" href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank">
       <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/87/87390.svg" /> 
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
      <script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
```

**CSS:**

```
#Contact {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:3em 0 0 0;
    min-height:100vh;
    background-color: var(--contact-bg);
  }

.other-section{
    font-size: 30pt;
    text-align:center;
    color: #EDF5E1;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
.contact-links{
      text-align: center;

    }
    #profile-link img{
      width: 50px;

    }
```

I cannot for the life of me get them to stay in the center of the page evenly spaced under Contact.

Comment: First you need to fix those tags, if you just would like to keep all that in the center of the page just use text-align center, and don't use multiple id attributes, use class instead, take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y6pmuobh/

Comment: @FernandoZamperin yes along the lines of what I want. I also want them pretty spaced out but still centered as well. But when I add margin to space them out they don't remain centered on the page. I also added #profile-link img{ width: 50px } so they are the same size.

Comment: You cannot declare same id name on same page change it into class otherwise use different names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can achieve that using [inline-block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

```css
:root{--contact-bg: white}
#Contact {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:3em 0 0 0;
    min-height:100vh;
    background-color: var(--contact-bg);
  }

.other-section{
    font-size: 30pt;
    text-align:center;
    color: #EDF5E1;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
.contact-links{
      text-align: center; 
    }
    .profile-link{
      display: inline-block;/*just add this*/
    }
    .profile-link img{
      width: 50px;

    }
```

```html
<section id="Contact">
  <h1 class="other-section">Contact</h1>
  <div class="contact-links">
    <a class="profile-link" href="https://facebook.com/" target="_blank">
     <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/21/21155.svg" />
    </a>
    <a class="profile-link" href="https://github.com/jadenadams329" target="_blank">
       <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25231.svg" />
     </a>
    <a class="profile-link" href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank">
       <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/87/87390.svg" /> 
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```